# Flip Between WorkBooks and write data

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I have a VSTO code that calls on a VBA code that is loaded onto the VSTO Ribbon Header. I was wanting to know if its possible (and how) you would be able to write a value from the VBA code onto the VSTO workbook. I have attached my code below.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Isitpossible
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void callVBA_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            String FilenamePath;

            FilenamePath = "C:\Test\MyWorkbook.xlsm"; //Where the workbooks where all the marco are stored

            //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilenamePath,0, true); 
            xlApp.Visible = false;


            //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
            xlApp.Run("Test");

        }
    }
}
```

My VBA sub is written here:

```
Sub Test()
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "This Works!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Application instance from your VSTO add-in:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

To access the object model of the host application, use the `Application` field of the `ThisAddIn` class. This field returns an object that represents the current instance of the host application. Read more about that in the [Access the object model of the host application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022#access-the-object-model-of-the-host-application) section on MSDN.

So, your code should look like that:

```
        private void callVBA_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            String FilenamePath;

            FilenamePath = "C:\Test\MyWorkbook.xlsm"; //Where the workbooks where all the marco are stored

            //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.

            xlWorkBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilenamePath,0, true); 
            xlApp.Visible = false;


Application.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;

            //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
            xlApp.Run("Test");

        }
```

See [Run a Macro from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997796/run-a-macro-from-c-sharp) for more information.